# Current Position in Titanium VideoPlayer

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the current position of a video being played in video player on iPhone (and maybe droid eventually).

The objective of this is to be able to keep track of how far through a video a user has gotten, and come back to pick up where they left off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Un-documented parameter in Titanium VideoPlayer... I got lucky on that one

The video player head position is exposed as `currentPlaybackTime`

```
var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({ contentURL: 'blablabla'});
win.add(activeMovie);

var played_time = 0;

var int = setInterval(get_the_time,1000);

function get_the_time()
{
    var played_time = activeMovie.currentPlaybackTime;
}
```

Comment: You can edit it. The edit button is right above the comment box, to the left of my "M" avatar.